# How to specify the size to record the screen with FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to record my computer screen, but I want to specify the area to ffmpeg record.

like:
height: 200
width: 300

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-video_size`option when using [x11grab](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#x11grab). Example to capture 300x200 area, offset 25 pixels to the right, and 100 pixels below the top left of the screen.

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size 300x200 -i :0.0+25,100 output.mp4
```

Or use `-grab_x` and `-grab_y`:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size 300x200 -grab_x 25 -grab_y 100 -i :0.0 output.mp4
```

Size and coordinates for a specific window can be found with `xwininfo | grep geometry`, then click on the target window to get coordinates. For example, an output of `-geometry 800x600+284+175` would result in using `-video_size 800x600 -i :0.0+284,175`.

Comment: I tried to record a window of 1920x1052+0--2 using the command:                                      ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size 1920x1052 -i :0.0+0,--2 output.avi, but it didnt work.

Comment: @henriquevital Not sure how you got `--2`. Try `ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size 1920x1052 -i :0.0 output.avi`

Comment: it works, thank you